# Webp support in apps

Tags: windows-phone-8

Is there any way I can add webp image support in my WP8 app?
My use will be downloading webp from url and displaying it. And uploading image from camera as webp.
In short a codec is needed.
Alternative:
https://cloudconvert.org/page/api#overview
Has anyone had any experience with this?

Comment: I tried importing Imazen WebP wrapper but the decode method returns System.Drawing.Bitmap which is not available in silverlight
Any ideas?
PS: Thanks 3dd for migrating this question. Being a new user I posted it in wrong section I guess.